# HTML Submit Button Is Navigating Away From the Page

Tags: javascript, html

I have a mobile app with a submit button. When I enter the parameters and hit submit, I want the page to reload with the new value displayed. For some reason, when I click submit, it navigates to index.html. I can't get it to stop. I've tried event.preventDefault(); and action = "saved_locations.html" but that took me to a weird pure html version of the page outside of the app.

```
<div class="pages">
<div data-page="saved_locations" id="saved" class="page navbar-through no-toolbar" align="center">
    <h2><br><u>Enter A Location<br><br></u>
        <form id="enter_location">
            Latitude: <input type="text" id="Latitude" value=""><br>
                Longitude: <input type="text" id="Longitude" value=""><br>
                    Location: <input type="text" id="Location" value=""><br>
                    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
        </form>
    <h2><u>Saved Locations</u></h2>

            </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Your `<form>` is invalid - you should provide a method (ie; post / get), and an `action` parameter would be useful.

Comment: Because you have no `action` in the `form` the page will just submit to root.

Comment: How is the form invalid? It does submit the value to localStorage. Is there an action that refreshes the current page instead of going to root?

Answer (score 0):

This is how a proper HTML form looks like. I'll do a basic example here:

```js
function showData() {
let x = document.getElementsByTagName("input")[0].value;
let y = document.getElementsByTagName("input")[1].value;
let z = document.getElementsByTagName("input")[2].value;
alert(`For the location ${z} the latitude is ${x} and the longitude is ${y}`);
}
```

```css
form {
font-weight: bold;
letter-spacing: 3px;
color: blue;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>HTML Form Example</title>
</head>
<body>

    <form action="https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52657111/html-submit-button-is-navigating-away-from-the-page">
      Latitude:<br>
      <input type="text" name="Latitude" value=""><br>           <hr/>
      Longitude:<br>
      <input type="text" name="Longitude" value=""><br><hr/>
       Location:<br>
      <input type="text" name="Location" value=""><br><hr/>
      <input type="submit" value="Submit" onclick="showData()">
    </form>
        
        <p id="demo"></p>

</body>
</html>
```

Like others in the comments suggested, you're missing an action. Here is a brief explanation of why is needed and what happens if it omitted:
The Action Attribute
The action attribute defines the action to be performed when the form is submitted.

Normally, the form data is sent to a web page on the server when the user clicks on the submit button.

In the example above, the form data is sent to a page on the server called "/server_side.php". This page contains a server-side script that handles the form data.

```
<form action="/server_side.php">
```

**If the action attribute is omitted, the action is set to the current page.** - [In your case the **root** index page].

Comment: Ok. Action="saved_locations" causes it to stay on the page after clicking submit. So that's good. Now I just need to figure out how to refresh the page after clicking submit. Currently, If I leave the page and come back, the new value is there. I have a function that creates div links on the fly from localStorage whenever this page is loaded. If I try to call that onclick, it doubles up the locations. I forgot to mention that I have an event listener for Submit that saves the inputs to localStorage. Here is a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/#run&togetherjs=Db5tsSFJPe

Comment: The default behavior of the browser is to refresh the page after a `submit`
 event. Usually, people want to avoid that behavior. Meaning, send the data to the backend, get the response back, do something with it while staying on the same page and without a reload. (so the current data isn't lost)

`location.reload();` will do it. 

Since SUBMIT takes some time, this would be a nice way to do it, using `setTimeOut` and setting it to a proper value.

`onsubmit="setTimeout(function(){window.location.reload();},10)`
So the browser has enough time to submit the form and then reload the page

Comment: I tried adding onsubmit="setTimeout(function(){window.location.reload();},10)" in the html div, and in the event listener in the JS. Neither option worked.

Comment: So, did you tried running my code snippet? It takes your inputs, does something with it, reloads the page, and stays on the same one, hence reload :)

Comment: Hey, you don't add that code inside of your `HTML` form. That's `JavaScript`. What you can/ should do is make a separate function that gets triggered when a `submit` occurs. -One similar to the one I provided earlier. I suggest looking at this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52675257/how-to-send-data-from-html-to-node-js/52675577#52675577). It's a similar situation, an answer I gave recently. It involves sending `form` data to the` backend`. Good luck :)

Comment: Yes, I added "setTimeout(function(){window.location.reload();},10)"  to the JS event listener. I just keep getting "Failed to load webpage with error: The requested URL was not found on this server." no matter what I try. Just tried  window.location.refresh(true); in the submit event listener.

Comment: Your server endpoint isn't set up correctly, hence **on this server.**. If your sending your data to `example/1` from your `HTML` form, there needs to be a corresponding server route `example/1` to catch that data, afterward you'll probably want to do something with it (save it to a DB, do your calculations,  change it in some form) and send a response back to your client in form of the changed data (which you previously configured on the backend), or/ and at least some type of validation (success, error). it's really all up to you and how you configure your **routes**, but they have to match.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that the issue is that I'm using Framework7 for my app. window.location.reload(); doesn't work, but this does:

```
setTimeout(mainView.router.refreshPage(),5);
```